# How to select tr whose first and second td contains specific value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have table that looks like this:

[image]

Code as follows:

```
<table id="table1">
    <tr>
        <td>HU</td>
        <td>BIP</td>
        <td>Pannon</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>HU</td>
        <td>BIP</td>
        <td>T-Mobile</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>HU</td>
        <td>BIP</td>
        <td>Vodafone</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>HU</td>
        <td>FUN</td>
        <td>Pannon</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>HU</td>
        <td>FUN</td>
        <td>T-Mobile</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>HU</td>
        <td>FUN</td>
        <td>Vodafone</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How to select last `<tr>` whose first `<td>` contains "HU" and second `<td>` contains "BIP".

I tried to select it like this:

```
$('#table1').find('tr td:first-child:contains("HU") td:nth-child(2):contains("BIP")').last();
```

Shows nothing

And like this:

```
$('#table1').find('tr td:first-child:contains("HU")').parent().each(function(i,e){
    console.log($(e).children('td:contains("BIP")').parent().last());
});
```

Doesn't show last `tr` but all of them(that contains "HU" and "BIP") instead.

Any idea?

Comment: Please include your HTML , not photo.

Comment: Try moving .last() from .parent().last() to the outside of .find().

Comment: You have to learn more about CSS [selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html). Whitespace between selectors matches **descendant element**. So `td:first-child td:nth-child(2)` in your code searches `td` **inside** another `td`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var target = $('table tr td:first-child:contains("HU")').parent().find('td:nth-child(2):contains("BIP")').last().parent();
    console.log(target.html());
});
```

```html
<script
    src="https:code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<table>
    <tr>
      <td>HU</td>
      <td>BIP</td>
      <td>Pannon</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>HU</td>
      <td>BIP</td>
      <td>T-Mobile</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>HU</td>
      <td>BIP</td>
      <td>Vodafone</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>HU</td>
      <td>FUN</td>
      <td>Pannon</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>HU</td>
      <td>FUN</td>
      <td>T-Mobile</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>HU</td>
      <td>FUN</td>
      <td>Vodafone</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

It first selects all first `td` containing *"HU"* then selects their parent `tr` and then again filters the result by finding the second `td` containing *"BIP"* and then finally selects the last matched element.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `eq()` and `includes()` methods.

> eq() reduces the set of matched elements to the one at the specified
>   index.

```js
var copy;
$('table tr').each(function(i,e){
    var first=$(this).find('td').eq(0).html().includes("HU");
    var second=$(this).find('td').eq(1).html().includes("PIB");
    if(first && second){
      copy=$(e);
    }
});
console.log($(copy).html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
     <td>HU</td>
     <td>PIB</td>
     <td>Pannon</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>HU</td>
     <td>PIB</td>
     <td>T-Mobile</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>HU</td>
     <td>PIB</td>
     <td>Vodafone</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>HU</td>
     <td>FUN</td>
     <td>Pannon</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>HU</td>
     <td>FUN</td>
     <td>T-Mobile</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>HU</td>
     <td>FUN</td>
     <td>Vodafone</td>
  </tr>
  
</table>
```